How to assign the result of mysqldump command into a variable?
In my bash script, I have tried
dumpresult=$(mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} > ${desdir}/${filename_sql})

and
dumpresult=`mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} > ${desdir}/${filename_sql}`

and
dumpresult=$(echo `mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} > ${desdir}/${filename_sql}`)

and
dumpresult=$(echo 'mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} > ${desdir}/${filename_sql}')

to get the result of the mysqldump command into a variable (in case of an error). However $dumpresult will remain empty. Any idea?
To make it clear, I need the mysqldump in a file (that works fine already) and the mysqldump error messages of stderr in $dumpresult.
Thanks a lot,
G.

You assign the standard output of the command to a variable, but since you redirect the stdout to a file, there is no stdout at all.
You can verify this by doing just a
mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} > ${desdir}/${filename_sql} 2>/dev/null

You will see that nothing is printed. Consequently, if you would assign the output to your variable, the variable would be empty.
To get the stdout to a file and into your variable, you have to do one of these:
dumpresult=$(mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} | tee ${desdir}/${filename_sql})

or
mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} > ${desdir}/${filename_sql}
dumpresult=$(<${desdir}/${filename_sql})

UPDATE
If you are interested in the stderr of the mysqldump, I suggest to use
dumpresult=$( (mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} | tee ${desdir}/${filename_sql}) 2>&1 )

or
dumpresult=$(mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} 3>&1 1>${desdir}/${filename_sql} 2>&3)

(UPDATE)
or even simpler
dumpresult=$(mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} 2>&1 >${desdir}/${filename_sql} 


Sorry, when I didn't make it clear:  I need the normal mysqldump output into a file > ${desdir}/${filename_sql} -- that works fine already.

However, when mysqldump encounters an error, it is routed to stdout, like "mysqldump: Got error: 1049: "Unknown database 'abc'" when selecting the database".  I just want to get the stdout error messages into the variable. Thx

@GaryU.U.Unixuser: I'm not a regular mysql user, but from what I know, the error messages are written to stderr, and you don't catch stderr anywhere. I will edit my answer to cope with this aspect (you really should have written in your question that you are interested in stderr)....

This one works like a charm:
dumpresult=$(mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} 3>&1 1>${desdir}/${filename_sql} 2>&3)
This one kind of works:
dumpresult=$( (mysqldump --user="${dbuser}" --password="${dbpw}" ${dbname} | tee ${desdir}/${filename_sql}) 2>&1 )
The dump is written into the file, but it is also written into $dumpresult, which is not intended. The first solution is perfect.
Thanks a lot!

You could simplify the redirections to not need a third file descriptor. cmd 2>&1 >/file will write stderr to the original stdout and stdout to the file.

@tjm3772 : Thanks, of course! I will edit it. Don't know why I didn't think of this simple solution.
